# How do I get content_shell to run my tests?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

There are questions for this already with answers, but I think this is something new.  I'm trying to get drone.io to run my tests in content_shell.  I've started the X server as per instructions.  Downloaded content_shell via the download_contentshell.sh script.  And executed content_shell according to the instructions I get both from the answers found here and from other sources.  The problem is none of them work.  content_shell will not run my tests, unless I give it an absolute file path, but if I do that, while it runs the tests, it fails, since the required imports aren't available to it.  Here is the what I do to run the test script in drone.io settings

```sh
sudo start xvfb
pub install
test/run.sh
```

Here is the run.sh script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

which content_shell
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    $DART_SDK/../chromium/download_contentshell.sh
    unzip content_shell-linux-x64-release.zip

    cs_path=$(ls -d drt-*)
    PATH=$cs_path:$PATH
fi

results=$(content_shell --args --dump-render-tree test/index.html 2>&1)
echo -e "$results"

# check to see if DumpRenderTree tests
# fails, since it always returns 0
if [[ "$results" == *"Some tests failed"* ]]
then
    exit 1
fi

if [[ "$results" == *"Exception: "* ]]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

Here is the dart test file

```dart
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:unittest/html_config.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

main() {
  // Ensure Polymer is looking for bound variables...
  addXParent();
  initPolymer();
  removeXParent();

  setUp(addXParent);
  tearDown(removeXParent);

  group("encountermap", (){
    test('has canvas element', (){
      new Timer(
        new Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
        expectAsync0((){
          expect(
            querySelector('encounter-map').shadowRoot.querySelector('canvas'),
            isNotNull
          );
        })
      );
    });

    test("contains file input element", (){
      new Timer(
        new Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
        expectAsync0((){
          expect(
            querySelector('encounter-map').shadowRoot.querySelector('input'),
            isNotNull
          );
          expect(
              querySelector('encounter-map').shadowRoot.querySelector('input'),
              new isInstanceOf<FileUploadInputElement>()
          );
          expect(
            querySelector('encounter-map').shadowRoot.querySelector('input').attributes['type'],
            contains('file')
          );
        })
      );
    });
  });
}

addXParent() {
  document.body.append(createElement('<encounter-map></encounter-map>'));
}

removeXParent() {
  querySelectorAll('encounter-map').forEach((el)=> el.remove());
}

createElement(String html) =>
  new Element.html(html, treeSanitizer: new NullTreeSanitizer());

class NullTreeSanitizer implements NodeTreeSanitizer {
  void sanitizeTree(node) {}
}
```

and the index.html file

```html
<head>
<!-- Load component(s) -->
<link rel="import" href="packages/RPGHelper/encountermap.html">
<script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/unittest/test_controller.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've watched as this test is run and all that happens is content_shell doesn't exit, stopping the script from finishing, thus timing out.  You can find the entire source for this project [here](https://github.com/terrasea/rpghelper)

This is really driving me up the wall.  Is this a bug?  And in case it makes a difference the version of dart I'm using is "Dart SDK version 1.1.0-dev.4.0"

Also this test runs perfectly in "Dart Editor version 1.1.0.dev_04_00 (DEV)", just not when using content_shell

Comment: I don't have an answer but voting for this issue is a good start: [Download `content_shell` automatically for Dart project setup](https://drone.uservoice.com/forums/176976-feedback-for-drone-io/suggestions/4933081-download-content-shell-automatically-for-dart-pr)

Comment: @zoechi actually in context of this question, voting for that issue isn't a good start, but all the same, you convinced me to vote for it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working after asking Chris Strom about it.  It seems I wasn't using the following

```
useHtmlConfiguration(true);
```

Seems silly, as I'm pretty sure I saw this somewhere else.  You also need to make sure, which I was doing all along that

```
import 'package:unittest/html_config.dart';
```

is done, since that's where

```
useHtmlConfiguration(true);
```

comes from.  This will make sure the right signal is sent to close the window is sent when all tests are finished.  Now my DroneIO tests pass :-)

Answer (score 1):

The new `test` package supports it out of the box.

Add `@TestOn('browser')` above your library statement in your `*_test.dart` file and run `pub global activate test` to install the new test runner and `pub global run test -pcontent-shell` to run the tests.

Until a stable release is published use `pub global activate test '>0.12.0-beta.6'` or `pub global activate -sgit git@github.com:dart-lang/test.git`

Also the `content_shell` version currently published with Dart isn't supported. Currently only the bleeding edge version is supported (see https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/68) but also Dartium, Chrome, FireFox, Phantom.js are supported now.